Каким словом можно заменить слово "квадробер"?
Квадробинг (квадробика) приобретает  популярность, особенно среди детей и подростков, хотя он появился совсем недавно.  Отличительная черта этой субкультуры заключается в том, что участники надевают костюмы и подражают животным.
Название «квадроберы» происходит от латинского слова quattuor, что означает «четыре», и термина «аэробика».
Слово «аэробика» происходит от английского aerobics и греческих корней 
«aer» — «воздух» и «βίος» — «жизнь». Термин придумал в 60-е годы ХХ века 
американский физиолог Кеннет Купер. Его книга «Аэробика» была издана в 
1963 году.

Но слово еще не устоялось в русском языке, существуют варианты квадробер, квадробир, кадробит и даже квадробрат. Но все они не передают точное значение слова, отсюда и расхождения. В том число квадробер можно соотнести с корневой основой бер, а это не прибавляет понимания.
Какой вариант слова можно придумать, чтобы значение было ясным, а произношение достаточно простым?

-бер- корень не получается. Квадроцикл, квадрокоптер, квадрозвук итд - везде ударение на корень. КвадрОбер - ударение на О, так что -бер- никак не корень. Квадробит, Квадробат итд, как раз можно спутать с корнями -бит- -бат- итд.

Ударение по-разному можно поставить, но в любом случае непонятно, откуда в слове Б. То есть по составу слова мы не можем определить его значение BIO, а это желательно было бы сделать (жизнь на четвереньках). К тому же у слова какая-то агрессивная фонетика, как будто чудовища какие. У меня точно такое впечатление от этой детской игры (если по слову).  Поэтому всем становится страшно) Почему-то вспоминаются  лангольеры — чудовища, которые пожирают пространство, из повести Стивена Кинга «Лангольеры».

"но в любом случае непонятно, откуда в слове Б.". Прекрасно понятно откуда. Каякинг - каякер, дайвинг - дайвер, майнинг - майнер, квадробинг - квадробер. Видим что весь англицизм всегда залетает в производителя действия. Оттуда и б. Сразу определяется англицизм "квадроб".

По составу русского слова желательно определить весь англицизм дословно. А там у них "квадроб" и есть. А уж дальше при желании нужно лезть в английский уже. Или можно изобрести слово, как у них, типа Квадроаэробат. Но это уже не англицизм будет (не заимствование), а полноценный русский язык

У вас англицизмы в приоритете)  А мне латинизмы милее, Вот, к примеру, слышу я впервые это слово, о квадробинге тоже ничего не знаю. Что за за кадроберы такие, не нужны они нам, запретить! А если бы я услышала BIO, то мне это слово знакомо, квадро от квадрат. Тогда нет вопросов, хорошая, наверное,  игра)

У вас англицизмы в приоритете) А мне латинизмы милее, Вот, к примеру, слышу я впервые это слово, о квадробинге тоже ничего не знаю. Что за за кадроберы такие, не нужны они нам, запретить! А если бы я услышала BIO, то мне это слово знакомо, квадро от квадрат. Тогда нет вопросов, хорошая, наверное, игра, надо попробовать)  // Сочините что-нибудь из квадро и био, но короткое, приятное на слух.

Ну нужно всего лишь совместить квадро + аэробику. В английском тоже корень BIO не прослеживается напрямую, и ничего живут спокойно. Квадробист может.

Вопрос — зачем?

Квадробер — слово неприятное на слух, агрессивное. Значение неясное. Квадробист лучше, суффикс ИСТ подходит для занятий чем-то.  Если уж квадробика стало у нас привычным словом.  Просто она не приветствуется в настоящее время.

Если речь идет о детской игре, то корни греческих или и латинских слов в ее названии лучше не использовать.
Привычно звучащие названия игр (прятки, городки, снежки, жмурки, салочки...) подсказывают возможный вариант названия игры – «четверАчки».
Видоизменяя это слово можно получить набор терминов, позволяющих ведущему комментировать ход игры и управлять ею. К примеру: участник игры – четверАч или четверАль(ка), быстро передвигаться – четверАсить, передвигаться медленно и неумело – четверЕнькать.
Надеюсь, что для детей это будет мимолетной забавой, а большую часть времени они будут играть подражая (не животным, а) своим родителям (их профессиям): нянька, повар, косарь, толмач, летчик, ямщик, водитель..., а еще есть музыка, танцы (не на четырех, а на двух лапках и даже на одной), рисование, чтение книг...
В подростковой среде такая игра могла бы называться «тетрастика» (от «гимнастика», через «тетра»), а участники игры – «тетраст» и «тетрастка».
Силюсь понять, что для участника - подростка в этой игре главное: проявить свои способности к перевоплощению, испытать себя необычными физическими нагрузками, почувствовать себя полноценным членом стаи или что то еще?
На мой взгляд, специальный костюм нужен участнику только для того, что бы компенсировать отсутствие собственного хвоста, а заодно и скрыть (по возможности) нехватку способностей на «основе воображения - и от имени (воплощаемого) персонажа совершать выразительные действия».
Кстати, слово «перевоплощение» появилось в результате основательной переделки слова «плоть»: https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/urovni-vladeniya-telom-v-iskusstve-dramaticheskogo-aktera

Четверачки?   Нет, не подойдет,  это для младшего детского возраста. Нужен именно латинский корень.

Судя по Вашему, Sharon, комментарию, мой ответ Вы прочли ровно до середины.

Как Вы считаете, для какого возраста латинские корни будут уместнее славянских или греческих?

Скорее наоборот)  // Начиная с 5 лет (а может, и раньше) дети прекрасно воспринимают латинские корни (влияние англосаксонской культуры))

Как прикажете Вас понимать: а) к пяти годам наши дети уже находятся под "влиянием англосаксонской культуры" или б) с пяти лет они готовы начать погружение в это самое?

Конечно, с пяти лет, а то и раньше) Так и понимайте. Они такие, эти дети)
Только родился, а уже телевизор смотрит. В год кнопочки  на телефоне нажимают, а уж с 5 лет вас проконсультирую по разным вопросам.

Вряд ли какой подросток захочет называться тетрастом.  Или это и есть цель?

Если смущает эта форма, замените на тетрастик и тетрастица. Будет немного длиннее...


Игру я бы назвала квадробиОника, чтобы сохранить корень BIO. Он несет положительные эмоции и отражает суть игры.

А вот участника игры как назвать? Варианты надо придумать на основе этого слова: квадробиОник, квадробиОн, квадрОбик, квадробИн, квАдрик (уменьш.)

С другой стороны, квадробика уже привычное название, тогда можно оставить:  квадрОбик (квадрик).

Неплохо смотрится предложенное мне квадробист, по аналогии с велосипедистом и теннисистом. То есть тот, кто занимается этими видами спорта (жаль, что автор слова отвечает в комментариях).



квадробионика это наука, а не игра. -бион- и -био-разные посылы несут. Квадробин это вообще бред, суффикс -ин- у исполнителя где-нибудь вы встречали?

Бред? Ну почему вы говорите такие слова? Это же невежливо, или все же нормально?)  // А квадробика  с аэробикой какие посылы несут, корень как у физики.  Поисковик не нашел науку "квадробионика", так что пока свободно, можно взять патент на название) // Почему вы так ограничиваете себя в свободе мышления,   суффикс ИН имеет отвлеченное значение, для разных слов подходит. Твори, выдумывай, пробуй.

"Твори, выдумывай, пробуй." Творить можно двумя способами. 1. Ты чего творишь б**? 2. Ну ты творец! Потому и ограничиваю - к первому способу не прибегаю.

Вежливо или нет, зависит от ситуации собеседника и прочего прочего. Вы же не обиделись значит нормально ;)

Не обиделась, да. Почему то вы иногда вызываете у меня чувство симпатиии)  // Маяковский с вами не согласен. Писатели вообще много новых слов придумали, хотя тоже творцы разные были. Некоторые галоши предлагали назвать мокроступами, только бы не galoches.
